# (Ilustrator CS6) Missing custom color swatches from gradient tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient, tools, swatches

I'm having a new problem that I'm 100% certain it wasnt there before.

On the top I'm pointing out my custom color swatches. As far as I can remember, If I wanted to add those colors to a gradient I had to double click on the color of the gradient. Then the color swatches list would pop up, **with my custom ones I just added**. Now for some reason it doesn't.

[image]

Now I have to manually copy thew hex color, enter in RGB mode, and paste the hex code. It's completely workflow ruinning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you saved those colors as gradient swatches.

Check if your colors are color swatches by changing the view mode at the Swatches panel bottom menu:

[image]

Instead of changing the gradient swatch from the gradient slider, try to drag the color from the Swatches Panel to the gradient position. If the color doesn't apply, there's something wrong in the swatch itself.

[image: d]

Comment: They are saved as pattern swatches, I don't konw how I did it hah. Also, when I treid to drag them it wouldn't let me to. Anyhow, I deleted them and re added them. Got them back to normal. Thanks a lot!